# Prompt a message "Press back button twice to return to app" in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, youtube, navigation, back-button

I am working on WP7 app.

In this am launching youtube url in Yotube app.

To return to my app from YouTube user will have to **click back button twice**, as per my research this is a known issue.

I need to show a message(inside youtube) to user like "Press back button again to return"  whenever he presses back button.

How can I achieve this?

Welcome any comment!!

Comment: Its not necessary.  We already know.  If anything, the first time the user is being sent out, show them a popup saying this will happen.  Then never bug them again about it.

Comment: Thanks! but I hope this won't create any problem in app certification?? One more question - can I show popup in Youtube? is this possible in Windows Phone?

Comment: This is the way all apps work on the Phone when they call an external browser or other app. I really don't think you'll need to do anything. Anyone who has used the phone for a while already understands this is the default behavior.

Comment: But, no, you cannot run a pop up on top of another app as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to display a popup in another application? In your case a Youtube-app?

Unfortunately, you can not change the behavior of another app. There aren't any hooks in other apps from your own app.

That is not possible.